# How do I specify custom comparator for the "in" keyword in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x

I am fairly new to Python, so I welcome alternative approaches.

I have a list of dictionaries that I start with (read from a file).
Now I have a bunch of additional dictionaries that I'd like to add to this list, but only if they are not in the original list.

However, I require that "not in the original list" is defined by a custom comparison function, rather than whatever Python uses as default.

More specifically, I want to compare certain key/value pairs in the dictionary, and if they are the same, return "true" for the expression.

```
myList = ReadFromFile...
newList = ReadFromFile...
for item in newList:
    if item not in myList: #I want custom behavior for this "in"
        myList.append(item)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`any`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#any):

```
any(customEquals(item, li) for li in myList)
```

If myClass is of a type that you can control, you can also overwrite the [`__contains__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__) method.

Comment: `customComparison` could probably be a lambda, too, if it's short enough.

Comment: There's still a loop inside that `any`, so if you have to do the `any` for each item in `newList`, this is still an O(m*n) algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

You don't.  The `in` operator is part of the language syntax.  What you want to do is something like this:

```
def comparison(item, otherContainer):
  # Code here for custom comparison.
  return True or False

for item in NewList:
  if not comparison(item, myList):
    myList.append(item)
```

Comment: Is there a faster than m*n way to do this cleanly in python (meaning, without implementing my own algo)?

Comment: @merlin2011 - Not unless there is some mechanism in your comparison function that eliminates the need for some of the checks.  Otherwise, `m*n` is as good as you're going to get.

Answer (score 1):

To address your comment on g.d.d.c's answer:

If your values are hashable (roughly speaking, this means they are immutable), the most efficient is probably to make use of Python's sets.  After reading in `myList`, generate a set of the values of interest from `myList`.  (If I'm reading your question right, you'll have a set of tuples generated from `myList`.)  Then when you loop over `newList`, you can test membership (again, of the values of interest) against that set, which is O(1) per test, yielding an algorithmic complexity of O(m+n).

You may want to use `operator.itemgetter` to grab the values of interest.

Comment: I don't mean to be pedantic - I'm genuinely curious: quote: `roughly speaking, this means they are immutable` How would you be able to hash a mutable?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: You wouldn't. A mutable object is never hashable. But a *so-called* immutable object is not always hashable. We often refer to tuples (for example) as "immutable". But really, they are only shallowly immutable. A tuple can contain a list, and that list is mutable, thus rendering the tuple unhashable. A tuple of integers would still be hashable.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a function of type `(object, object) --> bool` that tests for containment, there's already [one in the standard lib](http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html#operator.contains):

```
from operator import contains

myList = ReadFromFile...
newList = ReadFromFile...
for item in newList:
    if not contains(myList, item):
        myList.append(item)
```